# Query for the latest message in each conversation with every other user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `messages` for conversations between the users.
The table columns' names are:

```
messageID | fromUser | forUser | message | submitDate | seen
```

Sample data:

```
1  |  1 | 2 | "hi"             | "12341" | 0
2  |  2 | 1 | "hi"             | "12342" | 0
3  |  1 | 3 | "hi"             | "12343" | 0
4  |  1 | 4 | "hi 4"           | "12344" | 0
5  |  2 | 1 | "hello"          | "12345" | 0
6  |  1 | 2 | "hello how r u?" | "12346" | 0
7  |  3 | 1 | "hello user 1"   | "12345" | 0
```

How I can write a query to find the last message that was sent between myself and every other user in the system?
I mean last messages are:

```
between user 1 and 2 : "hello how r u?"
between user 1 and 3 : "hello user 1"
between user 4 and 1 : "hi 4""
```

My query:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT `fromUser`, `forUser`, `message`, `seen`, 
                          `username`, `userPhoto` 
          FROM `messages`,`user` 
          WHERE (`forUser`= '$myUserID' OR `fromUser`= '$myUserID')
                AND (((`forUser`= `userID`) AND (`forUser` !=  '$myUserID')) 
                   OR ((`fromUser`= `userID`) 
                   AND (`fromUser` !=  '$myUserID'))) 
          ORDER BY `submitDate` DESC";
```

but this query needs to fetch all messages in a conversation! I just need the last message.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE fromUser='1' AND forUser='2' ORDER BY submitDate DESC`?

Comment: i need to fetch last message of all conversations for user 1.

Comment: Anything you have tried so far? Why is submitDate a 5 character string?

Comment: i put my query. it is just sample data. but reall one is timestamp.

Answer (score 4):

Try this simple and easy one it will also find the users of each group Look at my code:-

```
select m.* ,u.*
    from
      messages m
      inner join (
            select max(id) as maxid
            from messages
            where messages.fromUser = "$myUsreId"
            OR messages.forUser = "$myUsreId"             
            group By (if(fromUser > forUser,  fromUser, forUser)), 
            (if(fromUser > forUser,  forUser, fromUser))
           ) t1 on m.id=t1.maxid 
      join 
      users u  ON u.id = (CASE WHEN m.fromUser = "$myUsreId"
                             THEN m.forUser
                             ELSE m.fromUser        
                         END)
```

Answer (score 2):

If `messageId` is an `auto_increment` primary key then you can use its values to distinguish which is the latest message in each conversation.  If `submitDate` has type `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` then would be another choice for that purpose, but if it has type `DATE` then its resolution is not sufficient.

The key thing, though, is to identify and filter on the timestamps or ids of the latest messages.  You can identify the IDs or timestamps on a per-conversation basis with a suitable aggregate (sub)query, and perform the filtering via an inner join, like so:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM
  messages m
  JOIN (
    SELECT
      MAX(messageId),
      CASE
        WHEN fromUser = '$myUserId' THEN forUser
        WHEN forUser = '$myUserId' THEN fromUser
      END AS otherUser  
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY
      CASE
        WHEN fromUser = '$myUserId' THEN forUser
        WHEN forUser = '$myUserId' THEN fromUser
      END
    HAVING otherUser IS NOT NULL
  ) other
    ON m.messageId = other.messageId
```

Comment: tnx John Bollinger . yes messageID is auto_increment . but this query just returns last message in last conversation for '$myUserID'. i mean it returns messageID -> 7 in that sample data. i need it return: messageID : 4,6,7 for user 1.

Comment: @Saeid, ok, I have revised my answer to meet the requirements according to your clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query to get the latest message for user with `userID = 1` per user conversation with some other user:

```
SELECT messageID, message, submitDate, otherUser
FROM (
   SELECT messageID, message, submitDate,
          @row_number:=CASE WHEN @other=otherUser THEN @row_number+1 
                            ELSE 1 
                       END AS row_number,
          @other:=otherUser AS otherUser             
   FROM (
      SELECT messageID, message, submitDate,
             IF(1 = fromUser, forUser, fromUser) as otherUser             
      FROM messages AS m
      WHERE 1 IN (fromUser,forUser) 
      ORDER BY otherUser, submitDate DESC) t ) s
WHERE s.row_number = 1
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9baa5/24)

The inner query:

```
SELECT messageID, message, submitDate,
       IF(1 = fromUser, forUser, fromUser) as otherUser             
FROM messages AS m
WHERE 1 IN (fromUser,forUser) 
ORDER BY otherUser, submitDate DESC
```

is used to return a list of messages *either sent or received* by user with `userID = 1`. Calculated column `otherUser` simply contains the other user, *either sender or receiver*, involved in the conversation with user with `userID = 1`.

In an outer query, variable `@row_number` is used in order to simulate `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY otherUser ORDER BY submitDate DESC)` available in SQL Server.

Finally, the outer query uses the number calculated by `@row_number` to select only the most recent message per `otherUser`.

Comment: tnx Mr Betsos. i tried your suggested query with my real data both in mysql and fiddle site. but results are different! in fiddle is ok but in mysql it has wrong answer. can you please check out this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f790/1    thankyou very much.

Comment: @Saeid In this fiddle demo user 1 has sent a message to himself. Results seem to be ok though. The most recent message per conversation has been returned.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I've [answered a nearly identical question on Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1981/9357).

`SELECT DISTINCT` is usually a sign that you have done something wrong.  It is nearly always possible to formulate a better query without needing `DISTINCT`.

A useful trick is to relabel senders and recipients in terms of interlocutor and self.  Then it's just a simple matter of filtering out the results.  Retain only those messages where `self` is the user in question.  Then, every row that has the same `interlocutor` conceptually constitutes a thread.

```
SELECT  fromUser, forUser, message, seen, otherUser.username, otherUser.userPhoto
    FROM
        (   -- Messages I sent
            SELECT *, forUser AS interlocutor, fromUser AS self
                FROM messages
            UNION
            -- Messages I received
            SELECT *, fromUser AS interlocutor, forUser AS self
                FROM messages
        ) AS thread_latest
        INNER JOIN users AS otherUser
            ON otherUser.userID = interlocutor
    WHERE
        self = '$myUserID' AND
        -- Discard all but the latest message in each thread
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT messageID
                (
                    SELECT *, forUser AS interlocutor, fromUser AS self
                        FROM messages
                    UNION
                    SELECT *, fromUser AS interlocutor, forUser AS self
                        FROM messages
                ) AS thread_later
                WHERE
                    thread_later.self = thread_latest.self AND
                    thread_later.interlocutor = thread_latest.interlocutor AND
                    thread_later.submitDate > thread_latest.submitDate
            )
    ORDER BY submitDate DESC;
```

Notice that there is a subquery that appears twice.  We can make it clearer by creating a view.

```
CREATE VIEW threads AS
    -- Messages I sent
    SELECT *, forUser AS interlocutor, fromUser AS self
        FROM messages
    UNION
    -- Messages I received
    SELECT *, fromUser AS interlocutor, forUser AS self
        FROM messages;

SELECT  fromUser, forUser, message, seen, otherUser.username, otherUser.userPhoto
    FROM
        threads AS thread_latest
        INNER JOIN users AS otherUser
            ON otherUser.userID = interlocutor
    WHERE
        self = '$myUserID' AND
        -- Discard all but the latest message in each thread
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT messageid
                FROM threads AS thread_later
                WHERE
                    thread_later.self = thread_latest.self AND
                    thread_later.interlocutor = thread_latest.interlocutor AND
                    thread_later.time > thread_latest.time
            )
    ORDER BY submitDate DESC;
```

---

I'll take this opportunity to point out that this query is where PostgreSQL really shines.  Two features in PostgreSQL (since version 8.4) make it easy.  The [`WITH` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/queries-with.html) lets you define a helper view in the query itself.  More importantly, 
[window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/tutorial-window.html) let you partition the threads by interlocutor, which is precisely the tricky part about this problem.

```
WITH threads(messageID, fromUser, forUser, message, submitDate, interlocutor, self) AS (
    -- Messages I sent
    SELECT *, forUser, fromUser FROM messages
    UNION
    -- Messages I received
    SELECT *, fromUser, forUser FROM messages
), myThreads AS (
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY interlocutor ORDER BY submitDate DESC) AS thread_pos
        FROM threads
        WHERE self = $myUserId
)
SELECT  fromUser, forUser, message, seen, otherUser.username, otherUser.userPhoto
   FROM my_threads
        INNER JOIN users AS otherUser
            ON otherUser.userID = interlocutor
    WHERE thread_pos = 1 -- Only the latest message per thread
    ORDER BY submitDate DESC;
```

Other databases, such as MS SQL Server and Oracle, also support window queries.  Consider switching from MySQL if you are doing anything serious involving SQL.